# Counting keywords from text file in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int c;

char* lib[5] = { "auto", "break", "char", "case", "const" };
char str[1000];
char buffer[300];
FILE *fp;

int main(){

    c = 0;

    fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("Error in reading file");
    }

    if (fp != NULL){
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            while (fgets(str, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL){
                if (strstr(str, lib[j]) != NULL) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d", c);
    }
    while (1){};
}
```

So I am trying to count the number of keywords in a text file. The code won't compile and states that the problems lie around the for loop and the strstr arguements. On a previous attempt it would compile but it wouldn't count the number of keywords, it just printed 0. Any ideas how i could fix this so that the code compiles or a another simple method for countinng the number of keywords in a text file.

Code snippets would be very helpful.

Comment: `while (1){};` is going to give you an infinite loop.

Comment: You want to read in your input and **then** scan it for matches from `lib`.  You also might want to use getline instead of fgets, or you will have to handle too long lines wrapping your input buffer.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. If your source actually looks like this, then doing so may well make you see "the problem" (which you don't actually state here what is, or any symptom of).

Comment: What is the program doing that is unexpected?  What are you expecting the program to do?  Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem was (before you edited it) that you had the proper nesting of your input loop and your searching loop reversed.

Also, as currently written you aren't really counting the total number of instances of the words in `lib` in your files because you don't properly handle the case where the same string (e.g. - "char") appears on a given line / input multiple times.

Here's a different version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *lib[5] = { "auto", "break", "char", "case", "const" };
  char       *str    = NULL;
  size_t      cap    = 0;
  int         c      = 0;
  const char *srch;
  FILE       *fp;
  int         i, j;

  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i, c = 0)
  {    
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(argv[i], "r"))) {
      perror(argv[i]);
      continue;
    }

    while (-1 != getline(&str, &cap, fp))
      for (j = 0, srch = str; j < 5; ++j, srch = str)
        while (NULL != (srch = strstr(srch, lib[j])))
        {
          const char *next_srch = srch + strlen(lib[j]);

          if ((srch == str || !isalnum(srch[-1])) && // ensure prev char not alphanumeric
              !isalnum(next_srch[0]))                // ensure next char not alphanumeric
            ++c;

          srch = next_srch;
        }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s: %d\n", argv[i], c);
  }

  if (str)
    free(str);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't compile for me, says getline is unndefined, any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you can replace getline with a call to fgets() using a large buffer and probably get equivalent behavior. getline just simplifies the case where a line is longer than your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

To get your code running just swap the while loop with your for loop.

And yeah, while (1){} does not make sense here.

EDIT:
The pure c-code i compiled and tested successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int c;              
char* lib[5] = {"auto", "break", "char", "case", "const"};
char str[1000];
char buffer[300];
FILE *fp;

int main(){

    c= 0;

    fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
    perror("Error in reading file");
    }

    if (fp != NULL){

        while( fgets(str, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL){
      for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if(strstr( str, lib[j]) != NULL) {
              c++;
            }
          }
        }   
        printf("c: %d", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Tried that there, no change. Oh and the While(1) was a line I forgot to remove.